# No wifi drivers detected and no proprietary drivers used

Tags: networking, drivers, nvidia, 18.04

I just installed a fresh copy of Ubuntu 18.04 on my Alienware 15R3. After installation it did not show my wifi in the top panel, but looking at `lspci` it gives me this entry

> 3e:00.0 Network controller: Qualcomm Atheros QCA6174 802.11ac Wireless Network Adapter (rev 32)

Which is my wireless card

Also checking `rfkill list`

```
0: hci0: Bluetooth
    Soft blocked: no
    Hard blocked: no
1: phy0: Wireless LAN
    Soft blocked: no
    Hard blocked: no
```

Running `sudo lshw -class network`

```
  *-network                 
       description: Ethernet interface
       product: Killer E2400 Gigabit Ethernet Controller
       vendor: Qualcomm Atheros
       physical id: 0
       bus info: pci@0000:3d:00.0
       logical name: enp61s0
       version: 10
       serial: 18:db:f2:50:0b:df
       capacity: 1Gbit/s
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: pm pciexpress msi msix bus_master cap_list ethernet physical tp 10bt 10bt-fd 100bt 100bt-fd 1000bt-fd autonegotiation
       configuration: autonegotiation=on broadcast=yes driver=alx latency=0 link=no multicast=yes port=twisted pair
       resources: irq:16 memory:dd400000-dd43ffff ioport:d000(size=128)
  *-network
       description: Wireless interface
       product: QCA6174 802.11ac Wireless Network Adapter
       vendor: Qualcomm Atheros
       physical id: 0
       bus info: pci@0000:3e:00.0
       logical name: wlp62s0
       version: 32
       serial: 9c:b6:d0:d4:dc:89
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: pm msi pciexpress bus_master cap_list ethernet physical wireless
       configuration: broadcast=yes driver=ath10k_pci driverversion=4.15.0-20-generic firmware=WLAN.RM.2.0-00180-QCARMSWPZ-1 ip=192.168.0.104 latency=0 link=yes multicast=yes wireless=IEEE 802.11
       resources: irq:134 memory:dd200000-dd3fffff
  *-network
       description: Ethernet interface
       physical id: 4
       logical name: enp0s20f0u2
       serial: 1a:a3:b4:d8:d0:4d
       capabilities: ethernet physical
       configuration: broadcast=yes driver=rndis_host driverversion=22-Aug-2005 firmware=RNDIS device ip=192.168.42.180 link=yes multicast=yes
```

And yet I can't see my Wireless options in the menu.

Now for the second problem(which I think is related to the first one)

Software & Updates is showing `No additional drivers available.` even when I have a Nvidia GTX 1070. How do I solve these problems. Please help

Comment: The info you posted shows `driver=ath10k_pci driverversion=4.15.0-20-generic` and `ip=192.168.0.104`, which means the driver is loaded and an IP is obtained. I don't know how many "wifi drivers" you need detected, and what are "my Wireless options in the menu".

Comment: I meant that even when it shows the wifi as connected as you mentioned above it does not show up in any settings. I can't see the wireless section or anything related to it in any UI